# Group policy proxy settings and Sql Server .NET Client Data Provider connections

Tags: sql-server, proxy, group-policy

Would the proxy settings enacted upon a user by a group policy configuration be applied to a Sql Server connection made by the Sql Server .NET Client Data Provider library, under the following conditions:

- The proxy settings are enabled to every protocol
- The proxy settings are bypassed for addresses listed in the local intranet trust zone
- The connection string specified for the client's connection is using an IP address
- The connection string is a trusted connection with integrated authentication
- The client and Sql Server are on two seperate machines
- The IP address, name or partially qualified wildcard name of the Sql Server is *not* enumerated within the list of proxy address exceptions
- The IP address, name or partially qualified wildcard name of the Sql Server is *not* enumerated within the list of sites belonging to the local intranet trust zone

I've read that it all uses WinSock, so I'm guessing that the proxy settings will be applied. Am I mistaken?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server drivers do not use the Internet proxy settings.

Comment: Hi mrdenny, thanks for your answer. Under what conditions could Sql Server client driver work with a proxy? Does it have to be specifically configured for the client driver, independent on the host environment's proxy configuration? Many thanks.

Comment: As far as I know the SQL drivers don't support using a proxy server at all.  You'll need to configure the network to support a direct connection to the remote SQL Server.